# IIS Web applications responding differently even though pointing to same place

Tags: iis

I have IIS configured with two web applications under the Default Web Site.  "Site1" and "Site2" are pointing to the same exact physical directory.  I went feature by feature in IIS to confirm that the configurations are identical in every way.  Site 1, after a few operations, will redirect to the login page, presumably because it lost session state.  Site 2 can be used indefinitely with no redirects.  Why is this happening?  (And no, suggesting to just use Site 2 is not an acceptable answer.  I have greatly simplified this for the sake of brevity.)

Comment: The design of IIS makes it very difficult to host two web apps with a single copy of content (as web.config can lead to conflicts). For your sake, use different copies for different sites.

Comment: Would this cause two sites that are pointing to the same place, with identical IIS configurations, to behave differently ?

Comment: if the settings are tuned for one, then they might not work for the other. Without posting more of your setup, this question won't be answerable.

Answer (score 0):

If two web applications point to the same physical directory with a single web.config file, they should behave in the exact same way.

If they don't we can assume the configuration differs from one to the other.

As the `web.config` file in the application root is the same for both, there are two locations you should check:

The web.config of the parent site and the `ApplicationHost.config` file

```
%sytemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

in these two files look for a `location` node with a path pointing to your applications like:

```
 <location path="Site2">
         ...
 </location>
```

The location nodes allow us to have different settings for different sites while using the same physical root directory.